# Incompatible Android emulator running in background

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I am Using the latest Android SDK in my Win 7. But whenever I try to launch my any android projects it shows the following window : [image]

I have checked the .android/avd/ folder but there are only 3 avds there. What is wrong with the AVD or anything wrong in my work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do you actually have an AVD instance running? If so, have you tried clicking OK when you hit that screen?
2. If you don't have an AVD running, have you tried restarting Eclipse/AVD Manager/your machine?

This dialog is indicating that you have an AVD running already. It's basically prompting you to select an AVD to send the app to. At least in my setup, selecting OK at this screen should run the app in the active AVD.

Comment: no @jkyuusai i don't have any AVD running .. and did try the restarting eclipse

Comment: Well, it's getting that AVD entry from somewhere. Have you tried either rebooting your machine or searching for (and killing) instances of the avd running in your process list in Task Manager? I think they should all start with the word emulator, but don't quote me on that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `adb tcpip 5554`. This will restart your ADB listening to the port 5554. The entry will go away.